# Will mysql Insert slow page down if its used on every request? PHP

Tags: php, mysql, ddos

I have a MVC framework that has a Request class which handles all requests. I log each request that comes in the database and the columns for the request log table is as follows:

1. ID (auto-increment)
2. Controller
3. Action
4. Params (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE)
5. Params (MVC params delimited by slash "/")
6. Request Method (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE)
7. Request Type (HTML, JSON, XML)
8. Is Request Ajax (true/false)
9. Referer URL
10. Request URI
11. Browser (User Agent Browser)
12. Browser Version
13. IP
14. Platform
15. Request Time (datetime)

Now that I think about it, if I have **100+** users online, each one making around **500+** requests a day I get **100*500 = 50,000** rows per day and per year it comes out around **18 Million**.

Now after **1-2** years if I dont clear the log, will it be slower for users to insert their request into the table?

Is it bad idea to log every request?

**Reason:**
the reason i want to log every request is to detect kind of DDOS attack so that if there are more than 10 requests per 30 seconds **lock** account for **20 minutes**.

Comment: Not a downvoter, but IMO it would make more sense to use an out-of-the-box network monitoring tool instead of rolling your own database solution. If you're being DDoS'ed, your system might be too clogged to react to the requests.

Comment: well its not only for DDos, I also want to use it for user trying to log in and fails multiple times. I lock his account if 3 failed attempts for 5 minutes.

Comment: You're logging every single request made to your database?  Have fun with that nightmare.  You do realize that there are server monitoring/logging capabilities available, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The amount of slowdown exhibited should mostly depend on the indexes you have on the table. Each record inserted will cause each index for that table to be updated, thereby creating more and more slow down as your table grows.

There are several ways to maintain performance over the long haul, the simplest being have your fresh data written to a MySQL Memory table for insertions and queries, then have a cronjob transfer the data to a permanent table.

There's also message queueing (ZeroMQ, RabbitMQ, etc) or a NoSQL database (MongoDB)

Answer (score 1):

> Reason: the reason i want to log every request is to detect kind of DDOS attack so that if there are more than 10 requests per 30 seconds lock account for 20 minutes.

Why not periodically delete logs older than a day or so, then? You're presumably not going to rate limit an account based off two year old accesses.